# Insert query issue- with foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I am new to SQL.  Need a help from you guys :)

I am building a java appl and stuck in one of the scenario for insert with foreign key. Suppose I have 2 tables **Employee_Type** and **Employee**:

Table **Employee_Type**
| idType | position |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1| Manager|

Table **Employee**

| empId | EmpName | emp_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |

`FK (emp_type) reference Employee_type(idType)`

Now values in **Employee_Type**
*1,

Manager*

I am inserting manually into **Employee** Table

```sql
INSERT INTO
   employee (empId, name, emp_type) 
VALUES
   (
      10, 'prashant', 1
   )
```

Here in above insert I am inserting manually **emp_type** which is **FK** . My question, is there any way to insert FK value automatically using select like below example?

```sql
INSERT INTO
   employee(empId, name, emp_type) 
VALUES
   (
      10, 'prashant', 
      (
         SELECT
            idType 
         FROM
            Employee_type,
            employee 
         WHERE
            employee.emp_type = employee_type.idtype
      )
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify your RDBMS and the syntax may therefore differ, but you should be able to restructure the statement to use literal values in an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`  format:

```
INSERT INTO employee (empId,name,emp_type) 
  SELECT 
    /* Build a SELECT statement which includes the static values as literals */
    '10' AS empId,
    'prashant' AS name,
    /* and the idType column */
    idType
  FROM Employee_type,employee 
  WHERE employee.emp_type=employee_type.idtype
```

Note that without anything else in the `WHERE` clause, the above will insert one row into `employee` for every row matched by the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Thanks Michael... i am using SQLite DB and ibatis

Comment: The syntax I have above is valid for SQLite.